# Multiplication and contraction of multiple metric tensors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

Do metric tensors commute?
Can I reduce this equation $$ (g_{hj}g_{ik}-g_{hi}g_{jk})g^{hl}, $$ as
$$ (g_{hj}g_{ik}g^{hl}-g_{hi}g_{jk}g^{hl}) $$
$$ =(g_{hj}g^{hl}g_{ik}-g_{hi}g^{hl}g_{jk}) $$
$$ =(A_{j}^{l}g_{ik}-A_{i}^{l}g_{jk}). $$
Now if $$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x^{l}},$$ where $\phi$ is a scalar, is multiplied to the above equation then:
$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x^{l}}(A_{j}^{l}g_{ik}-A_{i}^{l}g_{jk}).$$
And now contracting with $l$ we get:
$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x^{j}}(g_{ik}-g_{jk})$$
**Is this simplification allowed?**

Comment: For your use of $A$, the [usual symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) is $\delta$.

Comment: @MaazKhan You deleted [one of your other questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/643424/textbooks-for-quantum-field-theory-and-group-theory) after it had gotten a thoughtful answer. This is impolite.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they do commute. However, your last equation has a mistake: your $A^l_i$ tensor should contract with $\phi_{,l}$ to give $\phi_{,i}$. Your final answer should be
$$
  \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^j} g_{ik}-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^i} g_{jk}
$$
You can check the indices to see if your result is consistent.

Comment: Your indices are inconsistent. You have $jij$ in one term and $ijk$ in the other.

Comment: Just to clarify So does it mean that $$g_{hj}g_{ik}g^{hl}=g_{hj}g^{hl}g_{ik}$$ is always true

Comment: Fixed! Thanks @G.Smith
Yes, Maaz Khan, this is always true.

Comment: @MaazKhan The components of the metric tensor are just numbers at each point. So they commute.